# How to find and replace the footers and then convert the footers to plain text in word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Q1:**

Actually, i have to insert the page id like `<a id="page_1"/>, <a id="page_2"/>... n` in end of the page, so i have the below code for Insert Page numbers in each page.

```
Sub pagenosadd()
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
 .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.add _
 PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberLeft, _
 FirstPage:=True
 End With
End Sub
```

After run the macro, i have to find the page numbers and replace with `<a id="page_1"/>, <a id="page_2"/>...<a id="page_n"/>`

How to find and replace the footers?

**Q2:** How to Convert the footers to normal text in same page?

**Q3:** Or is it possible to directly add footers as `<a id="page_1">...n` and convert as text on the page?

It will be really very helpful to increase my skills?

**EDIT:**

Now, I have tried the below code for inserting footer as `<a id="page_1"/>...n`

```
Sub addfootaspage()

Dim k As Integer

For k = 0 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
k = k + 1
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(k)
        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "<a id=""page_" & k & "> "
    End With
Next k
End Sub
```

But inserted as `<a id="page_1"/>` to all the page, it's not counting the values.

Answer (score 0):

take look at the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515203/add-page-number-in-word-using-vba) or [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838955.aspx)

This example adds a page number to the primary footer in the first section of the active document.

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1) 
 .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add _ 
 PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberLeft, _ 
 FirstPage:=True 
End With
```

This example creates and formats page numbers in the header for the active document.

```
Set myPgNum = ActiveDocument.Sections(1) _ 
 .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _ 
 .PageNumbers.Add(PageNumberAlignment:= _ 
 wdAlignPageNumberCenter, FirstPage:= True) 
myPgNum.Select 
With Selection.Range 
 .Italic = True 
 .Bold = True 
End With
```

Comment: already, i have a macro for insert page number, now, i have to insert footer as "<a id="page_1">...n" on each page. OR how to increments the page value. thank you @Omar